# If I publish an update on Google Play without increasing the version code, will the new versions be available for new installations?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application published in Google Play.

My application had no compatibility with some screen size (was not shown to all devices), so I fixed that issue.

Now I would like to publish the fixed application, but without requiring an update for the people that has already installed my application.

Is this possible just without increasing the version number and update the fixed APK? Or do I have to do anything else?

If I publish the update, how long will the new version take to be available in the market?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You **CANNOT** upload an updated .apk file without incrementing `android:versionCode` value. Google Play will not allow you to proceed with such upload.

It may take a couple of hours for your update to appear in Google Play.

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to update the `versionCode`, but the `versionName` can stay the same.

So while it may be your second time you have uploaded your application, if the version name is the same as before, the user will not notice any difference.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will get an error when you are uploading your new APK file in to Google Play without change versioncode.